# How to forward lvalue reference?

Tags: c++11, pass-by-reference, perfect-forwarding, forwarding-reference

I have this code:

```
struct MultiMemoizator {
    template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
    ReturnType callFunction(std::function<ReturnType(Args...)> memFunc, const Args&... args) {
         return memFunc(args ...);
    }
};

int main()
{
    typedef vector<double> vecD;
    //filling vecD with random numbers...
    MultiMemoizator mem;
    function<vecD(vecD)> sort_vec = [](vecD &vec) {
        sort(vec.begin(),vec.end());
        return vec;
    };
    mem.callFunction<vecD,vecD>(sort_vec,vec);
    //vec is still not sorted!
}
```

Since `memFunc(args ...);` what happens is that a copy of `args` is sorted and not `vec`, so at the end `vec` will be unsorted after `callFunction(...)`.

I think that in order to solve this problem `forward` can help me, but if I try: `return cachedFunc(forward<Args>(args) ...);` then something bad happens (like `vector::size=0`).

How can I forward `args` reference to `sort_vec`?

Comment: I *think* you would only need forward if you had `const Args&&... args`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

specify return type as `Type&` or `const Type&` and return something that is not a temporary value.
Like this:

```
function<vecD&(vecD&)> sort_vec = [](vecD &vec) -> vecD& {
    std::sort(vec.begin(),vec.end());
    return vec;
};
```

p.s. you vere trying to sort `const` vector.